# How to always show entire height and width of background image used in Bootstrap 4 Jumbotron?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I searched extensively for a solution, including reading similar questions here on stackoverflow, but cannot find an answer. We are using Bootstrap 4.5.1 and have a jumbotron div with a 1920x800 background image that needs to show the entire height and width of the image for all viewpoints. I found solutions that come close, but they either the sides of the jumbotron image gets cut off, the bottom of the image gets cut off, or a lot of space is added beneath the jumbotron image when viewing on smaller devices.

Here's what we have so far:

CSS

```
.jumbotron {
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background: url(../img/jumbotronbackground.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
   <div class="jumbotron bg-cover">
      <div class="container-fluid p-0">
         <div class="container bodyCopy">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-12" style="max-width:760px;">
                  <div class="container">
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                           <div class="card-body-right">
                              <h1 class="card-title">Headline goes here</h1>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-12">
            <p>More content goes down here, but it needs to be flush against the bottom of the jumbotron.</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: so I guess you need to push the image into the div instead of the body? have you tried to use those css lines?  `.jumbotron: { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; z-index: -1; }` and then for `body { background-color: transparent; }`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That didn't do it. I put it outside of .container-fluid so there would be no container to prevent it from full height and width.

Comment: What is the actual image size?

Comment: 1920x800 - I have to add it as a background since there's a text overlay.